# Trying to pass multiple values through a Python Function with loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, social-networking

I wrote a function (or am trying to) to get stats from a social media service called Crowd Tangle and print out the stats for the first five posts. I am trying to figure out how to use a loop to pass the value 0 through 4 in the function to call the correct JSON nodes. I am using Python 3.6 and Spyder. Instead of copying the function five times and writing 0,1,2,3,4, is there a way to use a loop to do this? Any suggestions or links would be great. Thanks.

```
import requests 

def get_crowdtangle_stuff():
    url = 'https://api.crowdtangle.com/posts?token=mytoken'
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    #print(json_data)

    Platform = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['platform']
    Platform_string = str(Platform)
    print('This stupid thing was on the ' + Platform_string + '.')

    Title = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['message']
    Title_string = str(Title)
    print('This stupid thing was on the ' + Title_string + '.')

    Date = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['date']
    Date_string = str(Date)
    print('This stupid thing was posted on ' + Date_string)

    Like_count = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['statistics']['actual']
    ['likeCount']
    Like_count_string = str(Like_count)
    print('This stupid thing got ' + Like_count_string + ' likes.')

    Shares = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['statistics']['actual']
    ['shareCount']
    Shares_string = str(Shares)
    print('This stupid thing got ' + Shares_string + ' shares.')

    Comments = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['statistics']['actual']
    ['commentCount']
    Comments_string = str(Comments)
    print('This stupid thing got ' + Comments_string + ' comments.')

    Wow_count = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['statistics']['actual']
    ['wowCount']
    Wow_count_string = str(Wow_count)
    print('This stupid thing got ' + Wow_count_string + ' wows.')

    Total_engagement = Like_count + Shares + Comments + Wow_count
    Total_engagement_string = str(Total_engagement)
    print('This stupid things total engagement score is ' + 
    Total_engagement_string + '.')

    Link = json_data['result']['posts'][0]['link']
    Link_string = str(Link)
    print('This stupid thing has a link of ' + Link_string + '.')

get_crowdtangle_stuff()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter `n_records` to your function to represent the number of JSON records you want to print.  Then in your function you can create a loop:

```
for n in range(n_records):
    ...Rest of your code here where you can use n to retrieve the JSON record and print the outputs your want...
```

Then you can input a number to represent how many records you want to print when you call the function, i.e.:

```
get_crowdtangle_stuff(5)
```